# running php on ubuntu through shell - unlink & fopen always fail

Tags: php, xml, ubuntu, curl, fopen

I am trying to delete an xml file, and then re-create it with data from an xml feed using cURL.

my PHP code is as follows:

```
function get_file($file, $local_path, $newfilename){
//Delete old xml file first

unlink('../../xml/file.xml');

// Create a new one
$out = fopen($local_path.$newfilename,"wb");

if ($out == FALSE){
    print "<br>File not opened<br>";
    exit;
}

$ch = curl_init();

// Setup options, where to write etc
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 28800);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);

// Execute
curl_exec($ch);

// Close
curl_close($ch);
}

// get_file(url_of_file, directory_to_put, filename);
get_file('XML FEED URL', '../../xml/', 'file.xml');
```

this code used to work fine until I moved to an Ubuntu virtual server.
I want to use the code by running the following command:

```
php ../var/www/html/php/cron/download_xml_feed.php
```

the xml folder (and current xml file) are located at ../var/www/html/xml

Every time I run the command however it gives me:

```
PHP Warning:  unlink(../../xml/jobs.xml): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/php/cron/download_xml_feed.php on line 7

PHP Warning:  fopen(../../xml/jobs.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/php/cron/download_xml_feed.php on line 10
```

this will eventually be a crontab run with the above command

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Have you tried using absolute instead of relative paths?

Comment: @PatrickLee Have just tried and it works! just got to go through all my cron scripts and change the paths. thank you!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. When you said you moved to another server, directory structure came to mind immediately.